# how to prevent dublicate data with validation in laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-livewire

I want to prevent data dublication in db so need to use validation.If the same classroom was used before there should be an error message "this classroom already exists". How to create a custom validation like this in laravel?

here's my current code:

```php
<div class="sm:col-start-1 sm:col-end-3 col-span-3  ">
    <x-select x-on:change="isShowing = $event.target.value" name="classroom_id" label="{!! __('Sınıf') !!}" wire:model="classroom_id"
            id="classroom_id"
            :options="$this->classes"/>
    <x-jet-input-error for="classroom_id" class="mt-2" />
</div>

<div class="col-span-2 " x-show="isShowing">
    <label class="tf-form-label" for="course_name">
        {{ __('Ders') }}
    </label>
    <input wire:model.debounce.250ms="course_name" type="text" name="course_name" id="course_name" class="tf-input" />
    <x-jet-input-error for="course_name" class="mt-2" />
</div>
```

```php
public function saveCourse(){
    $this->validate(['course_name' => 'required','classroom_id' => 'required']);
    
    $course = new Course();
    $course->name = $course_name;
    $course->classroom_id = $classroom_id;
    $course->save();
  
    $this->render();

}
```

Comment: So you are alloting class to each course and you don't want same class can be assigned to multiple courses right ??

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

you can use rule unique

```
...
$this->validate([
    'classroom_id' => 'required|{TableName}',
]);
...
```

reference https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it using the validation method "unique", and define in it the table and column which you're going to check

```
$this->validate([
  'course_name' => 'required',
  'classroom_id' => 'required|unique:courses,classroom_id'
]);
```

on edit method, this approach changes, once you need to ignore the validation of this field if no change is made on it. Then you can do this

```
$this->validate([
  'course_name' => ['required']
  'classroom_id' => ['required',Rule::unique('courses','classroom_id')->ignore('id',$this->course->id)]
]);
```